# How to edit "chrome://settings/cookies?search=third+" programmatically using java script

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have a requirement to add websites url to "Allowed to use third-party cookies" in "chrome://settings/cookies?search=third+.
I could not find material in web which explains about how to edit privacy settings in chrome using javascript or any other UI technology.

Can you please help me with any reference if this can be achieved ?

Is this operation actually allowed by chrome ?

We are thinking about this solution as we need to add a site to the allowed list to share third party cookies.

Comment: You mean from the JavaScript that is executed from a web-page? Because that is not be allowed. It would be a bit of a security risk if any malicious website could just change the privacy settings on behalf of the user.

Comment: This sounds like something that would be done via workstation policy administration, not from code.  Unless you're looking to do this from a browser extension that the user has to install?

Comment: Yes,  from the JavaScript that is executed from a web-page.